# Python: Hvplot Dashboard: Getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'owner'

Tags: python, hvplot

I am creating dashboard, where user can select file from given directory and dashboard will show aggregated summary. Also user can select aggregation based on his needs. I am running command "panel serve .ipynb to execute the notebook.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import bokeh
import hvplot.pandas
import panel as pn
import param
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('plotly')
pn.extension()
PALETTE=["#ff6f69", "#ffcc5c", "#88d8b0"]

output_dir = r'C:\Users\navee\Desktop\GL' # change to the desired directory
files = pn.widgets.FileSelector(output_dir)

@param.depends('files', watch=True)
def file_rd(files):
    if files.value:
        df = pd.read_csv(files.value[0])
        print(df)
        print("File Selected :", files.value[0])
        idf = df.interactive()

        GroupByOptions = ['agg1', 'agg2', 'agg3', 'agg4', 'agg5']
        OtherColumns = [i for i in df.columns if i not in GroupByOptions]

        CheckBoxGroup1 = pn.widgets.CheckBoxGroup(name='Groupby Options', value=['agg1'], options=GroupByOptions)
        CheckBoxGroup2 = pn.widgets.CheckBoxGroup(name='Other Column Options', value=['amount'], options=OtherColumns)
        ipipeline = (idf.groupby(CheckBoxGroup1.value)[CheckBoxGroup2.value].sum().reset_index().reset_index(drop=True))
        itable = ipipeline.pipe(pn.widgets.Tabulator, pagination='remote', page_size=20, sizing_mode = 'stretch_width')

        # layout template
        template = pn.template.FastListTemplate(
            site='MY Dashboard',
            title='Interactive DataFrame',
            main=[files,itable.panel()],
            sidebar=[pn.pane.Markdown('## GroupBy Options'),
            CheckBoxGroup1, 
            pn.pane.Markdown('## Aggregated Column Options'), 
            CheckBoxGroup2])
        return template.servable()
    
pn.Column(files, file_rd)
```

Pandas: '1.4.4'
hvplot: '0.8.0'
panel: '0.14.4'

DUMMY data looks like:

[image]

Thanks!